# How to find link-local address of the other device?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip-address, ipv4

What command can I use to find the link-local address of the device I am connected to? I am connected to the other device via link-local ONLY so entering its normal IPv4 address no longer works. `ip list` does not help either because it only shows my ip address. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

If that address is known to your computer (there's no inherent reason your computer should know before the other one sent a packet and even after they did, they might have changed their address for any reason), `ip neigh` would know about the entries in the ARP table.

There's a standardized way of getting all connected computers with a link-local address to send a packet: a broadcast ping. However, sometimes the firewalls of operating systems unhelpfully block these even on link-local addresses.

There's also cleverer ways to detect who, in a network you don't know, offers a specific service (e.g., a database, or a file share, or a media server), but that kind of depends on what services you hope to access on that other computer.